# Find the real number $x$ such that $\det A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3\\ x & x^2 & x^3 & 1 \\ x^2 & x^3 & 1 & x \\ x^3 & 1 & x&x^2  \end{bmatrix}$$

I don't know how to approach this. I'd like to figure this out step-by-step so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the role of $y$ here?  I don't see it anywhere in $A$.

Comment: Sorry there are this is a question with multiple questions and the others have y. I will remove it.

Comment: My guess, from eyeballing it, is $x = 1, i, -1, -i$.

Comment: If you restrict yourself to real $x$, then you end up singular if $x = \pm 1$.  Don't see any others at the moment.

Comment: I must have some sort of proof though, because or else it would just be guessing and that isn't enough.

Comment: Well, by inspection, $\det A$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree 12; and if $1+x+x^2+x^3=0$, then $(1,1,1,1)$ is in the null space of $A$ so $\det A = 0$; therefore, $1+x+x^2+x^3$ divides this polynomial.  Similarly, if $1-x+x^2-x^3=0$ then $(1,-1,1,-1)$ is in the null space so $1-x+x^2-x^3$ divides the polynomial...

Comment: Did you even *try* to compute the determinant (as a function of $x$)?

Comment: Put it to upper triangle form. Then the determinant is the product of the diagonals. Should just be a case of solving a polynomial then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By performing column operations we can evaluate the determinant to be $(x^4-1)^3$. So, the roots are $1$, $-1$, $i$ and $-i$.

Try $C_2 \to C_2 - xC_1$ and $C_4 \to C_4 - xC_3$. This will easily simplify the determinant into:

$\det A= \left| \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & x^2 & 0\\ x & 0 & x^3 & 1 - x^4\\ x^2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ x^3 & 1-x^4 & x&  0\end{matrix}\right|$

Answer (score 1):

With row operations that don't change the determinant (sum to a row another row multiplied by some factor):
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & x^2 & x^3 \\
x & x^2 & x^3 & 1 \\
x^2 & x^3 & 1 & x \\
x^3 & 1 & x & x^2
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & x^2 & x^3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1-x^4 \\
0 & 0 & 1-x^4 & x-x^5 \\
0 & 1-x^4 & x-x^5 & x^2-x^6
\end{bmatrix}
&&\begin{aligned}
R_2&\gets R_2-xR_1\\
R_3&\gets R_3-x^2R_1\\
R_4&\gets R_4-x^3R_1
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
Now we can expand the determinant with respect to the first column:
$$
\det A=
\det\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1-x^4 \\
0 & 1-x^4 & x-x^5 \\
1-x^4 & x-x^5 & x^2-x^6
\end{bmatrix}
=-(1-x^4)^3=(x^4-1)^3
$$